# Inserting fetched records into new table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm fetching some records with below query:

```
;with tb1 as (select * from tb where condition), select ... from tb1 join tb2 condition
```

I want to insert the records fetched with the above query to a new table. How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
select * into NewTable from (followed by above query)
```

and this:

```
;with Tb1 as (select * from tb where condition), select * into NewTable from (select ... from Tb1 join tb2 condition)
```

But it doesn't work. Any tips? Thanks.

EDIT:

Acutal QUERY which I need to insert into New Table:

```
; with dub as
(select docnumber, sum(amount) summedamount from stg_invoice_cust_vw where year(crmcreateddatetime)=2017
group by docnumber
having count(docnumber)>1)
select dub.docnumber, dub.summedamount, sup.slamount SLAmount, (dub.summedamount - sup.slamount) diff from STG_INVOICE_SUP_VW sup inner join dub on dub.docnumber = sup.docnumber
where (dub.summedamount - sup.slamount) <> 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a `SELECT` you just follow the CTE with a `SELECT INTO`:

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
   SELECT x = CONVERT(int, 1)
)
SELECT x INTO dbo.TrashMe FROM cte;
```

With your new query:

```
; with dub as
(
  select docnumber, sum(amount) summedamount 
  from stg_invoice_cust_vw where year(crmcreateddatetime)=2017
  group by docnumber
  having count(docnumber)>1
)
select 
  dub.docnumber, 
  dub.summedamount, 
  sup.slamount SLAmount,
  (dub.summedamount - sup.slamount) diff 
-----------
INTO dbo.NEW_TABLE_NAME --<--------------------------- *** HERE ***
-----------
from STG_INVOICE_SUP_VW sup 
inner join dub on dub.docnumber = sup.docnumber
where (dub.summedamount - sup.slamount) <> 0
```

Note you can only do this *once*... the next time you run this code, you will get an error that `NEW_TABLE_NAME` already exists.